# Cassandra - no viable alternative at input '('

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to execute a simple Cassandra table statement. I am getting an error like this. I am a bit new to it.

My query is:

```
create table orders
(
  id bigint,
  order_number bigint,
  supplier_id bigint,
  planned_delivery_date timestamp,
  flow_type int,
  store_number bigint,
  tenantid text,
  qc_locked boolean,
  qc_locked_by text,
  qc_finished_at timestamp,
  qc_finished_by text,
  qc_reviewed_at timestamp,
  qc_reviewed_by text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,flow_type,supplier_id,(tenantid,order_number))
);
```

I am getting an error this:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="li
ne 17:40 no viable alternative at input '(' (... KEY (id,flow_type,supplier_id,[
(]...)">
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by adding an extra set of parentheses to  (tenantid,order_number) ?

Comment: Those two are compound unique key. I don't have much idea, how to specify compound unique in Cassandra, can help me please, if I am wrong

Comment: Pro posting tips: I notice you're adding a lot of chatty/pleading material (I need help, please help me, would anyone kindly help, etc). You may find that this is irritating to native English speakers, so doesn't actually encourage folks to help; in any case, since you're adding it to _all_ your questions, that's more work for volunteer editors, who like to trim this sort of thing. Thank you if you can cut it down in the future.

Comment: @Sun Pls select one of the answers as a correct answer if it helps!

Answer (score 3):

If what you are trying to create a table with a composite partition key you need the parentheses around the columns making up that part of the primary key not around the remaining clustering keys.

This will work:

```
create table orders
(
  id bigint,
  order_number bigint,
  supplier_id bigint,
  planned_delivery_date date,
  flow_type int,
  store_number bigint,
  tenantid text,
  qc_locked boolean,
  qc_locked_by text,
  qc_finished_at date,
  qc_finished_by text,
  qc_reviewed_at date,
  qc_reviewed_by text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id,flow_type,supplier_id),tenantid,order_number)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Cassandra, the primary key has two parts: **partition key**(required) and **clustering key**(optional).

- Using partition key you specify how Cassandra distributes data among
  nodes
- using clustering key you specify how Cassandra stores data in each
  node

Specifying primary key in creating a table in the form

```
PRIMARY KEY (f1, f2, f3, f4)
```

by default, the first element (here `f1`) is the partition key and any field after that (here `f2, f3, f4`) are considered clustering key.

If you want to set partition key including more than a field you should put them in the parenthesis **at the first**. For example in your code, supposing `id,flow_type,supplier_id` are the partition keys, you should use:

```
create table orders
(
  id bigint,
  order_number bigint,
  supplier_id bigint,
  planned_delivery_date timestamp,
  flow_type int,
  store_number bigint,
  tenantid text,
  qc_locked boolean,
  qc_locked_by text,
  qc_finished_at timestamp,
  qc_finished_by text,
  qc_reviewed_at timestamp,
  qc_reviewed_by text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id,flow_type,supplier_id),tenantid,order_number)
);
```

**Notice**: The condition in queries (like *where* statement) just can use fields that are part of primary key (both partition keys and clustering keys) and fields with secondary indexes. For example, you **cannot** use the following queries for this table:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE qc_reviewed_by == "A" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for defining primary key is wrong, In a primary key  the first part is the partition key and the second part is the clustering column.

Primary key (partition key, Clustering Column);

While defining Primary keys you can use either compound key or composite key.

Compound key:
A multi-column primary key is called a Compound Key :  Primary key (partition key, Clustering Column);

Composite key:
A partition key based on multiple columns : Primary key ((partition key1, partition key2));

Note:
If you use composite key then the where clause in your query should contain all the columns used for defining the partition key.